# Combining error terms from two Taylor expansions

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

When deriving the five-point differentiation formula as shown in [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=zXnSxY9G2JgC&pg=PA190&lpg=PA190&dq=%22Intermediate%20Value%20Theorem%201.11%20implies%20that%20a%20number%22&source=bl&ots=pWoGtOGRQW&sig=tgcq6UumiKAZLozw4xywK_9pC4c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gzjFUNn7H-6N0QHS6oCwDw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Intermediate%20Value%20Theorem%201.11%20implies%20that%20a%20number%22&f=false), the IVT was used to combine $ f^{(5)} (\xi_1) $ and $ f^{(5)} (\xi_2) $ into one error term, $ f^{(5)}(\tilde{\xi}) $

As the book says 
[here](http://books.google.com/books?id=zXnSxY9G2JgC&pg=PA190&lpg=PA190&dq=%22However,%20an%20alternative%20method%20can%20be%20used%20to%20show%20that%22&source=bl&ots=pWoGtOFPOW&sig=aoa-qD8l3JJS9H-a76XJ0g1EKfI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vzPFUNa9HYK69QS_noHQCw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22However,%20an%20alternative%20method%20can%20be%20used%20to%20show%20that%22&f=false), another method is used to combine $ f^{(5)}(\tilde{\xi}) $ and $ f^{(5)}(\hat{\xi}) $.

What is the method used here?

Comment: What's the relation between $\xi_1$, $\xi_2$, $\tilde{\xi}$ and $\hat{\xi}$?

Answer (score 0):

You're still using IVT, just in a way that's a little more subtle.

You want to show that there exists $\xi$ such that $4f^{(5)}(\hat{\xi}) - f^{(5)}(\tilde{\xi}) = 3f^{(5)}(\xi)$.

Or, written differently, show exists $c$ such that $f(a) + \frac{f(a) - f(b)}{3} = f(c)$. And this is straightforward by IVT.

Edit: No, sorry I was wrong. You can't use IVT to solve this. And in fact, this isn't true in general. Burden/Faires is assuming that $h$ is sufficiently small to make it work by continuity of $f$. But it seems to me that this proof won't work when $f(a)$ is a positive local maximum of $f$ without making $h = 0$.